# What's difference between regex{m,n} and (regex){m,n}?

Tags: java, regex

I'm developing a docker project, need to write a regex to check repository name. 
Requirement as follow:

1. only include ASCII charactors, exclude upcase.
2. special charactors exclude except for dot(.), hyphen(-) and underline(_).
3. only start with alphabet and number and also end with it.
4. special charactors can't appear continuously.
5. length limit(min:2, max: 255)

then, my regex is:

```
([a-z0-9]+(?:[._-][a-z0-9]+)*){2,255}
```

but, it can't be OK, when repository name is `e-e_1.1`

When I change it to:

```
[a-z0-9]+(?:[._-][a-z0-9]+)*{2,255}
```

it's OK.

Is there someone can explain? Thank you in advance.

Comment: `regex{m,n}` matches "rege" followed by `m` to `n` times "x" character, `(regex){m,n}` matches "regexregexregex..regex" (`m` to `n` times)

Comment: @MarounMaroun regex specify an regular expression, not specify an string of "regex"

Answer (score 8):

In the `([a-z0-9]+(?:[._-][a-z0-9]+)*){2,255}` regex, the limiting quantifier `{2,255}` is applied to the whole pattern inside Group 1 (`[a-z0-9]+(?:[._-][a-z0-9]+)*`). It means it can be repeated 2 to 255 times. It does not mean the whole string length is restricted to 2 to 255 characters.

Now, your `[a-z0-9]+(?:[._-][a-z0-9]+)*{2,255}` regex can match unlimited characters, too, because the string matched with `[a-z0-9]+` can have 1 or *more* characters. `(?:[._-][a-z0-9]+)*` can match zero or more characters. The limiting quantifier `{2,255}` does not work here at all the way you need.

To restrict the length of the input string to 2 to 255 characters, you will have to use a lookahead anchored at the start:

```
^(?=.{2,255}$)[a-z0-9]+(?:[._-][a-z0-9]+)*$
 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

The `(?=.{2,255}$)` lookahead will be executed only once at the beginning of the string and a match will only be found if the condition inside the lookahead is met: there must be 2 to 255 characters (`.` matches any characters other than a newline, but it is not important as you only allow specific characters in the matching pattern later) up to the end of the string.

Comment: thank you very much, i learned a lot. I think I have a long way to go about regex, thank you for your answer!

Comment: The way does not have to be long. Read the [*Lookahead Example: Simple Password Validation*](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html#password) shortcut article :)